# Detect when music player is being paused

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I wonder if it's possible to detect when the the music in my "iPod" on the phone is being paused, not if it's paused or currently playing, just the moment when the music is being paused. I guess i should be using `AVAudio`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MPMusicPlayerController` has a method:

```
+(MPMusicPlayerController *)iPodMusicPlayer;
```

> The iPod music player employs the iPod app on your behalf. On
>   instantiation, it takes on the current iPod app state and controls
>   that state as your app runs. Specifically, the shared state includes
>   the following:
>
> Repeat mode (see “Repeat Modes”) Shuffle mode (see “Shuffle Modes”
>   Now-playing item (see nowPlayingItem) Playback state (see
>   playbackState) Other aspects of iPod state, such as the on-the-go
>   playlist, are not shared. Music that is playing continues to play when
>   your app moves to the background.

You can check its `playbackState` which may be:

```
enum {
   MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped,
   MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying,
   MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused,
   MPMusicPlaybackStateInterrupted,
   MPMusicPlaybackStateSeekingForward,
   MPMusicPlaybackStateSeekingBackward
};
typedef NSInteger MPMusicPlaybackState;
```

You can also get notified if its `playbackState` change with the `MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification`.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer;
-(void)iPodMusicPlayer
{
    musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer]; 
    switch ([musicPlayer playbackState]) 
    {
        case: MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped:
            NSLog(@"iPod player is stopped)";
            //Do something
            break;
        case: MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused:
            NSLog(@"iPod player is paused");
            //Do something
             break;
        case: MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying:
            NSLog(@"iPod player is playing");
            //Do something
             break;
        //Etc.
        default:
           break;
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(musicPlayerPlayBackStatusChanged:) 
                                                 name:MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                                object:nil];

    [musicPlayer beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
}

-(void)musicPlayerPlayBackStatusChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    switch ([musicPlayer playbackState]) 
    {
        case: MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped:
            NSLog(@"iPod player is stopped)";
            //Do something
            break;
        case: MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused:
            NSLog(@"iPod player is paused");
            //Do something
             break;
        case: MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying:
            NSLog(@"iPod player is playing");
            //Do something
             break;
        //Etc.
        default:
           break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be right! :) I just can`t put in my code, can you show me how to use in an IF statement, lika this: "if (Music.player == pause){}

Comment: Work Perfectly!!:) Do you know if there is a way to do this with all the music on my iPhone? (Spotify, podcaster, soundcloud etc)?, Maybe I need som kind of api in that case :/ TY!