# MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork not displaying in UIImageView (iOS 8) with other MPMediaItems not updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, ios8, mpmediaitem

When trying to grab and display song covers/artworks with `MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork`, they fail to display in my `UIImageView`. Additionally, with the other `MPMediaItems` showing the Artist Name and Song Name, they do not update when the song is changed.

**This is my .h file:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *songtitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *songartist;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nowplaying;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *songalbumart;


@end
```

**This is part of my .m file that has the `MPMusicPlayerController` content:**

```
MPMusicPlayerController *player = [MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer];

MPMediaItem *item = [player nowPlayingItem];

NSString *songtitlestring = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
NSString *songartiststring = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
NSString *nowplayingstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#NowPlaying %@ by %@, via @TweetPlaying", songtitlestring, songartiststring];

self.songalbumart = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];

self.songtitle.text = songtitlestring;
self.songartist.text = songartiststring;
self.nowplaying.text = nowplayingstring;
```

Anyone know how to resolve these issues of:

- MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork not displaying (`IBOutlet` is connected!)
- MPMediaItems of the UILabels to display Artist Name and Song Name not updating when song is changed by user

I am developing for iOS 8 and am there using `MPMusicPlayerController's` `systemMusicPlayer` as `iPodMusicPlayer` is depreciated.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:** So I have to use `MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification`, can anyone provide an example for my situation?

Comment: `[self.songalbumart setImage:[[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(songalbumart.frame.size.width, songalbumart.frame.size.height)];` ? You say that info are not updating, but do you listen when the music change?

Comment: @Larme I am using an IBOutlet to link the MKMediaPropertyArtwork to a UIImageView on my Storyboard though, will that code still work? And no, the application isn't listening when the music changes, would you be able to provide a solution for that possibly?

Comment: I think that you still may be able to use `
MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification` There should be some example on the web.

Comment: @Larme Can you provide something I could like at? Can't find anything quite relevant to my situation.

Comment: Look for example using `iPodMusicPlayer`, and replace it by `systemMusicPlayer`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788671/detect-when-music-player-is-being-paused/25788824#25788824 (and change the notification that you listen but you'll get how it works).

Comment: @Larme Just tried `[self.songalbumart setImage:[[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(songalbumart.frame.size.width, songalbumart.frame.size.height)];`, doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: Is `[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork]` nil?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62348/discussion-between-rastudios-and-larme).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MPMediaItemArtwork is null while cover is available in iTunes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998621/mpmediaitemartwork-is-null-while-cover-is-available-in-itunes)

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me.

```
MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [mediaItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
UIImage *artworkImage = [artwork imageWithSize: albumImageView.bounds.size];

if (artworkImage) {
    albumImageView.image = artworkImage;
} else {
    albumImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"noArtwork.png"];
}
```

Got answer from [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/UsingTheiPodLibrary/UsingTheiPodLibrary.html)